# When you add a dynamic style, it returns NaN although the class is prescribed and the variable returns true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-modules

I add a class like this `:class="{[$style.header-hidden]: hideHeader}"`

The function that is responsible for the variable

```
onScroll() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 92) {
        this.hideHeader = true;
    }
},
```

It returns true, but the class returns NaN
[image]

Comment: perhaps it's `$style.header-hidden` that is `NaN` or is that `TheHeader_1L83S`

Comment: @Bravo But that's how we define class, tell me how to do it right

Comment: @Bravo hideHeader is the variable that is responsible for adding the class (header-hidden), is it originally false, or is it something else?

Comment: @Bravo value of $style.header-hidden is NaN  TheHeader_1L83S is initial class of this block

Comment: oh, I'm a derp ... of course it's `NaN` ... think ... `$style.header - hidden`

Comment: you want `:class="{[$style['header-hidden']]: hideHeader}"`

Comment: @Bravo ty, add this in answer

Comment: no, because it's javascript 101, how to access a property with special characters :p